# Implementación de predicción en ANN

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

estoy iniciando en DL y encontré este código de una ANN con numpy y necesito ayuda para adaptarlo o implementarlo al data que cuento:

Data: 
https://mega.nz/#!TJM31IoY!HJUAxfB-Plp9Nl4u1un05t_RXscZJ15lxNHySrjghi8

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

class Neuralnet:
    def __init__(self, neurons, activation):
        self.weights = []
        self.inputs = []
        self.outputs = []
        self.errors = []
        self.rate = 0.5
        self.activation = activation    #sigmoid or tanh

        self.neurons = neurons
        self.L = len(self.neurons)      #number of layers

        eps = 0.12;    # range for uniform distribution   -eps..+eps              
        for layer in range(len(neurons)-1):
            self.weights.append(np.random.uniform(-eps,eps,size=(neurons[layer+1], neurons[layer]+1)))

    def train(self, X, Y, iter_count):

        m = X.shape[0];

        for layer in range(self.L):
            self.inputs.append(np.empty([m, self.neurons[layer]]))        
            self.errors.append(np.empty([m, self.neurons[layer]]))

            if (layer < self.L -1):
                self.outputs.append(np.empty([m, self.neurons[layer]+1]))
            else:
                self.outputs.append(np.empty([m, self.neurons[layer]]))

        #accumulate the cost function
        J_history = np.zeros([iter_count, 1])


        for i in range(iter_count):

            self.feedforward(X)

            J = self.cost(Y, self.outputs[self.L-1])
            J_history[i, 0] = J

            self.backpropagate(Y)


        #plot the cost function to check the descent
        plt.plot(J_history)
        plt.show()

    def cost(self, Y, H):     
        J = np.sum(np.sum(np.power((Y - H), 2), axis=0))/(2*m)
        return J

    def feedforward(self, X):

        m = X.shape[0];

        self.outputs[0] = np.concatenate(  (np.ones([m, 1]),   X),   axis=1)

        for i in range(1, self.L):
            self.inputs[i] = np.dot( self.outputs[i-1], self.weights[i-1].T  )

            if (self.activation == 'sigmoid'):
                output_temp = self.sigmoid(self.inputs[i])
            elif (self.activation == 'tanh'):
                output_temp = np.tanh(self.inputs[i])


            if (i < self.L - 1):
                self.outputs[i] = np.concatenate(  (np.ones([m, 1]),   output_temp),   axis=1)
            else:
                self.outputs[i] = output_temp


    def backpropagate(self, Y):

        self.errors[self.L-1] = self.outputs[self.L-1] - Y

        for i in range(self.L - 2, 0, -1):

            if (self.activation == 'sigmoid'):
                self.errors[i] = np.dot(  self.errors[i+1],   self.weights[i][:, 1:]  ) *  self.sigmoid_prime(self.inputs[i])
            elif (self.activation == 'tanh'):
                self.errors[i] = np.dot(  self.errors[i+1],   self.weights[i][:, 1:]  ) *  (1 - self.outputs[i][:, 1:]*self.outputs[i][:, 1:])

        for i in range(0, self.L-1):
            grad = np.dot(self.errors[i+1].T, self.outputs[i]) / m
            self.weights[i] = self.weights[i] - self.rate*grad


    def sigmoid(self, z):
        s = 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-z))
        return s

    def sigmoid_prime(self, z):
        s = self.sigmoid(z)*(1 - self.sigmoid(z))
        return s    


    def predict(self, X, weights):

        m = X.shape[0];

        self.inputs = []
        self.outputs = []
        self.weights = weights

        for layer in range(self.L):
            self.inputs.append(np.empty([m, self.neurons[layer]]))        

            if (layer < self.L -1):
                self.outputs.append(np.empty([m, self.neurons[layer]+1]))
            else:
                self.outputs.append(np.empty([m, self.neurons[layer]]))

        self.feedforward(X)

        return self.outputs[self.L-1]



activation1 = 'sigmoid'     # the input should be scaled into [ 0..1]
activation2 = 'tanh'        # the input should be scaled into [-1..1]

activation = activation1

net = Neuralnet([1, 6, 1], activation) # structure of the NN and its activation function

#TRAINING

#Esta es mi Data actual.....
path = pd.read_csv('Data_Balanceada.csv')
entradas = path.iloc[:,0:11].values
salidas = path.iloc[:,-1].values


m = 1000 #size of the training set
X = np.linspace(0, 4*math.pi, num = m).reshape(m, 1); # input training set


Y = np.sin(X) # target

kx = 0.1 # noise parameter
noise = (2.0*np.random.uniform(0, kx, m) - kx).reshape(m, 1)
Y = Y + noise # noisy target

# scaling of the target depending on the activation function
if (activation == 'sigmoid'):
    Y_scaled = (Y/(1+kx) + 1)/2.0
elif (activation == 'tanh'):
    Y_scaled = Y/(1+kx)

# number of the iteration for the training stage
iter_count = 20000
net.train(X, Y_scaled, iter_count) #training

# gained weights
trained_weights = net.weights

##########    PREDICTION

m_new = 40 #size of the prediction set
X_new = np.linspace(0, 4*math.pi, num = m_new).reshape(m_new, 1);

Y_new = net.predict(X_new, trained_weights) # prediction

#rescaling of the result 
if (activation == 'sigmoid'):
    Y_new = (2.0*Y_new - 1.0) * (1+kx)
elif (activation == 'tanh'):
    Y_new = Y_new * (1+kx)

# visualization
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.plot(X_new, Y_new, 'ro')
plt.show()

raw_input('press any key to exit')
```

Me tira este error cuando reemplazo variables por la data:

```
shapes (73,12) and (2,6) not aligned: 12 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Comment: ¿cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: Cómo puedo ingresar la data que tengo a la red neuronal

Comment: ¿eso lo has indicado en tu post?, ¿qué has intentado?¿has tenido algun error o problema?

Comment: Si, cuando reemplazo X, y por entradas, salidas me tira este error : shapes (73,12) and (2,6) not aligned: 12 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Comment: Eso lo debes señalar en tu pregunta ¿no crees?, te recomiendo leer [ask], pasa el [tour] y mejora tu pregunta.